# Twisted Threading + MapReduce on a single node/server?

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, mapreduce

I'm confused about Twisted threading.

I've heard and read more than a few articles, books, and sat through a few presentations on the subject of threading vs processes in Python.  It just seems to me that unless one is doing lots of IO or wanting to utilize shared memory across jobs, then the right choice is to use multiprocessing.

However, from what I've seen so far, it seems like Twisted uses Threads (pThreads from the python threading module).  And Twisted seems to perform really really well in processing lots of data.

I've got a fairly large number of processes that I'd like to distribute processing to using the MapReduce pattern in Python on a single node/server.  They don't do any IO really, they just do a lot of processing.

Is the Twisted reactor the right tool for this job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer to your question: **no**, twisted threading is not the right solution for heavy processing.

If you have a lot of processing to do, twisted's threading will still be subject to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Without going into a long in depth explanation, the GIL is what allows only one thread at a time to execute python code. What this means in effect is you will not be able to take advantage of multiple cores with a single multi-threaded twisted process. That said, some *C modules* (such as bits of SciPy) can release the GIL and run multi-threaded, though the python code associated is still effectively single-threaded.

What twisted's threading is mainly useful for is using it along with blocking I/O based modules. A prime example of this is database API's, because the db-api spec doesn't account for asynchronous use cases, and most database modules adhere to the spec. Thusly, to use PostgreSQL for example from a twisted app, one has to either block or use something like `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` which is a wrapper that uses `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread` to allow a SQL query to execute while other stuff is going on.  This can allow other python code to run because the `socket` module (among most others involving operating system I/O) will release the GIL while in a system call.

---

That said, you can use twisted to write a *network* application talking to many twisted (or non-twisted, if you'd like) workers. Each worker could then work on little bits of work, and you would **not** be restricted by the GIL, because each worker would be its own completely isolated process. The master process can then make use of many of twisted's asynchronous primitives. For example you could use a `DeferredList` to wait on a number of results coming from any number of workers, and then run a response handler when all of the `Deferred`'s complete. (thus allowing you to do your map call) If you want to go down this route, I recommend looking at `twisted.protocols.amp`, which is their Asynchronous Message Protocol, and can be used very trivially to implement a network-based RPC or map-reduce.

The downside of running many disparate processes versus something like `multiprocessing` is that

1. you lose out on simple process management, and
2. the subprocesses can't share memory as if they would if they were forked on a unix system.

Though for modern systems, 2) is rarely a problem unless you are running hundreds of subprocesses. And problem 1) can be solved by using a process management system like [supervisord](http://www.supervisord.org/)

---

**Edit** For more on python and the GIL, you should watch [Dave Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/)'s talks on the subject ( [website](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/) , [video](http://blip.tv/file/2232410), [slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) )

Comment: You can use a module like Ampoule to do the process management for you.  It's also not clear how much Python processes benefit from fork()-derived COW pages, since CPython writes to pages almost continuously (to update reference counts).